# how to Use Image in Header instead of header Text in MVC view's web grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

I have to show image in Web Grid Header instead of Header text .
this is my web grid column

```
grid.Column("TotalEmail","TotalEmail",style: "regClass"),
```

css for this is

```
.regClass {
 width:35px;
 :55px;
 background-image: url("../../images/Icon/emailicon.png");
 opacity:5;
 border:1px solid red;
 }
```

still it is not showing image on header while it is showing image in Data field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing it this way.. First searching the text and then replacing it with the image

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".webgrid-table th").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text == "TotalEmail") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/Images/circles.jpg"/>');
        }
    });
});
```

Just use the table class and fetch text and then replace it with Image.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: It works for me. I search on the basis of header class .